# Is $\delta$ always a function of $\epsilon$?

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

In the epsilon-delta definition of limit, $\delta$ seems to rely on $\epsilon$. Of course, $\delta$ can be a constant, and it doesn't have to look like a continuous. But I'm not sure what the problem is with the expression $\delta:\mathbb{R}^{>0}\to\mathbb{R}^{>0}$. Is there any reason why this statements are not common?

Comment: it rely on $\epsilon $ but its not a function because for any chosen $\epsilon >0$ there are uncountable many valid values for $\delta $

Comment: Introducing a function like this for an existential quantifier under the scope of a universal quantifier is closely related to the notion of Skolemization in logic. It's a standard thing. I find this kind of notation handy for making it explicit that, for example, the modulus of continuity of a generic continuous function depends on $\epsilon$ and $x$, while for a uniformly continuous function it only depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: The one catch though is that $\delta$ isn't uniquely defined, given any valid function $\delta_1(\epsilon)$, any function with $0<\delta_2(\epsilon) \leq \delta_1(\epsilon)$ is also valid.

Comment: For constant functions, $\delta$ can be whatever you want it to be, so it does not have to be a function of $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @Ian That's also interesting to me. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions are a concept which are useful, but not universally so. Many things can technically be considered functions, but we only introduce this viewpoint when it helps to describe or understand a certain object, i.e. when it seems convenient, which it isn't here. In order to think of $\delta(\epsilon)$ as a function we must first pick such a $\delta$ given $\epsilon$ (since it is not uniquely defined), coming down to a more-or-less arbitrary choice, and after we've gone through the effort of doing so we do not gain anything. This view of $\delta$ as a map $\mathbb R_{>0}\to\mathbb R_{>0}$ did not make theorems regarding limits easier to prove, or the definition easier to understand, or allowed us to gain anything at all in terms of analysis. That's why this view, while correct, is not at all common.

Comment: Hear hear for the pragmatic point of view. This is especially so in many situations in the analysis of partial differential equations where you have so many levels of $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s that the functional notation actually makes it easier to keep track of the dependency (and prevent you from making a circular argument) than a long string of quantifiers.

Comment: If I had found an explanation like your answer in the textbook, I would have understood the definition more easily without being intimidated by logical symbols. In that sense, even if the definition itself is left intact, I think my view is also meaningful as a secondary explanation. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @istist Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

For the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$ we have a unique function $\epsilon \mapsto \delta_{\text{max}}(\epsilon),$ where $\delta_{\text{max}}(\epsilon)$ is the maximal valid $\delta>0$ for a given $\epsilon>0$.

But we usually do not take $\delta$ be the maximum possible (this confuses students first learning $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proofs). Instead we make a choice $\delta(\epsilon) < \delta_{\text{max}}(\epsilon)$. The choice is a function. It is not unique, though; several choices are possible. The choice is taken so that it's easy to show that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x - a| < \delta.$

Thus we have functions, $\delta_{\text{max}}(\epsilon)$ and the choice $\delta(\epsilon)$, but as [YiFan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/496634/yifan) writes, it doesn't gain us much thinking of them as functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the point. The point is that, given an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, it should be possible to find a $\delta>0$ such that blah, blah, blah. You should see $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definitions as a "challenge": if you are challenged with a $\varepsilon$, you should be able to find a $\delta$ to answer the challenge.

Comment: But what's wrong with saying $\exists \delta: (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ satisfying "[hypothesis] $<\delta(\epsilon) \implies$ [conclusion]$< \epsilon$"?

Comment: It's not wrong, but it is not necessary. When you are looking at real-analysis exercises, the  $\delta $ will always be explicit. But, "in the wild", I have seen proofs where the existence of  $\delta $ is proven without an obvious way to produce an explicit value for a given  $\varepsilon  $. In such situation, the "function" point of view is counterproductive in my opinion.

Comment: @MartinArgerami can you give an example of a proof where the existence of the delta is proven but without it being a function of epsilon?

Comment: @user1035015: easy examples come from proofs where compactness is used. For instance, the function $g(x)=e^{-x^2}$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$. This means that given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y|<\delta$ implies that $|e^{-x^2}-e^{-y^2}|<\varepsilon$. Maybe it's possible, but I wouldn't know how to find $\delta$ explicitly, given $\varepsilon$.